# Maximize a tabpanel in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I know only window have a maximize config in ExtJS, tho I was thinking of maximize a tabpanel to the whole body of the page when a user would click on a button.

I think it's possible as Iv' seen this : http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?268067-How-can-we-add-maximize-and-minimize-in-EXTJS-4-portal

but I can't adapt it to my case.

Here's my tabpanel

```
            {
            region: 'center',
            tabPosition: 'top',
            title: 'Représentation',
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            id: 'panel1',
            cls: 'tabpanel-container',
            tools:[{
                type:'maximize',
                tooltip: 'Agrandir la fenêtre',
                handler: function(e, target, panel) {
                    var c = panel.up('viewport');
                    var testPanel = Ext.getCmp('panel1');
                    var con=panel.ownerCt;
                    c.insert(0,con);
                    c.doLayout();
                }
            }],
            header: {
                titlePosition: 1,
                titleAlign: 'left',
                height: 36,
                cls: 'tabpanel-header'
            },
            activeTab: tabType,
            border: false,
            split: false,
            collapsible: false,
            margins: '5 0 5 0',
            items: [...]
            }, [...]
```

When clicking on the tool, the tabpanel just dispapear from the page, no error is triggered in the console.

Any hints ?

Comment: I have no hints for your problem, but why not trick the user into thinking they maximized that tabpanel?  When they click the maximize button, you throw the panel into a maximized window... they won't know the difference.

Comment: You mean, when you click, you create a modal window where you push the tabpanel ? Why not.

Comment: Yessir.  I'd say if anything, give it a try... if it looks awful, then keep pursuing this option.  Sorry I can't be of further assistance.

Comment: It's OK, your idea is interesting ! I'll keep it updated.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating ExtJS sources for Window component and Floating mixin I've come up with this solution: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/triclozan/Q8wsL/)

Handler that does the magic looks as following:

```
    handler: function (e, target, panelHdr) {
        var panel = panelHdr.up('panel');
        if (!panel.maximized) {

            panel.restoreSize = panel.getSize();
            panel.restorePos = panel.getPosition(true);
            panel.maximized = true;
            var parent = panel.ownerCt,
                container = parent ? parent.getTargetEl() : panel.container,
                newBox = container.getViewSize(false);
            panel.setBox(newBox);
        } else {
            var newBox = panel.restoreSize;
            newBox.x = panel.restorePos[0];
            newBox.y = panel.restorePos[1];
            panel.maximized = false;
            panel.setBox(newBox);
        }
    }
```